Karate Parallel test report generation issue
I executing parallel tests with 5, 3, and 2 threads:

For a Scenario Outline
With 5000 examples

At the execution moment i don´t have any problems, but, when i search for the report i get this error:
15:52:06.502 [pool-2-thread-1] WARN  com.intuit.karate.JsonUtils - object to json serialization failure, trying alternate approach: Java heap space
15:52:07.015 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate.Suite - <<error>> unable to write report file(s): classpath:features/Release2_e2e/procesoE2E.feature - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space


I tried to assign more memory to Java (12gb) and i still having the problem.
Also i tried to use

karate.configure('report', { showLog: false});"

(i don't know if still working) in Karate config file and log still showing.
i'm using Karate 1.3.1, java 17, Junit5 with Gradle... Thanks for helping!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your principle problem is that you are reading all the data at once into memory (as the error reports). It will be doing this before it commences the execution of even the first test.
Rather, you need to feed the data to Karate for each Scenario.  Karate supports this, see JSON Function Data Source.
So then using a JSON function acquire the data in chunks. Assuming that you have you data in a class Scenario Outline "table", then copy that into a file and read one line at a time from the file system, parse, etc.  Given there is good interoperability with Java in Karate you'll likely be able to do the same using Java.
(By the way, don't paste images of error messages (or most anything else), here's why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378)

Thanks Andrew, i will try it... it's my first time here, thanks for the advice!
